# I cannot figure out why I am getting the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) Express

Tags: javascript, express, pug, sequelize.js

I am a student in a online JavaScript Tech Degree program, so clearly I am a rookie. I am building an app using express, pug and sequelize. In my first version of the app I had the first block of code which brought back a listing of Patrons. It worked just fine but was a basic listing with no search capabilities and no pagination capabilities. Here is the code:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {

Patron.findAll({
    order: [
        ['last_name', 'ASC'],
        ['first_name', 'ASC']
    ]
}).then(patrons => {

    const columns = [
        "Name",
        "Address",
        "Email",
        "Library ID",
        "Zip"
    ];

    const patronData = patrons.map(patron => {
        return patron.get({
            plain: true
        });
    });

    const title = 'Patrons';

    res.render('all', { patronData, columns, title, content });
});
```

});

Now I am trying to add the search capabilities and the pagination and I have modified my code to look like this:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {

    // no page selected - so page = 1
    if (req.query.page === undefined) {
        res.redirect(
            '/patron?page=1'
        );
    }

    let workingQuery;

    //  set search flag to true or false
    search = req.query.search ? req.query.search : false;

    // a query with no search parameters
    if ( req.query.search === undefined ) {
        workingQuery = Patron.findAndCountAll({
            order: [
                ['last_name', 'ASC'],
                ['first_name', 'ASC']
            ],
            offset: (req.query.page * 10) - 10,
            limit: 10
        });
    }

    //  query for patrons with search parameters (for pages other than page 1, page 1 handled in the POST above)
    if (req.query.search) {
        workingQuery = Patron.findAndCountAll({
            where: {
                last_name: {
                    $like: `%${ req.body.last_name.toLowerCase() }%`,
                },
                first_name: {
                    $like: `%${ req.body.first_name.toLowerCase() }%`,
                },
                library_id: {
                    $like: `%${ req.body.library_id.toLowerCase() }%`,
                }
            },
            offset: (req.query.page * 10) - 10,
            limit: 10
        });
    }

    //  render the patron query
    workingQuery.then(patrons => {
        currPage = req.query.page;

        const columns = [
            "Name",
            "Address",
            "Email",
            "Library ID",
            "Zip"
        ];

        const patronData = patrons.map(patron => {
            return patron.get({
                plain: true
            });
        });

        const title  = 'Patrons';

        res.render('list_selector', { 
            entity,
            title,
            filter,
            columns,
            patronData 
        });

    }).catch(error => {
        res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});
```

Now this is what appears in my viewport window:

```
{}
```

And this error is returned in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I am going to include my relevant pug files (in case they help):

```
body
#top.header
    a.top(href='/#top')
        img.logo(src='/static/images/librarian.png', alt='librarian')
    h1.app-title Welcome to Library Manager
    h3.head-books Books
    h3.head-patrons Patrons
    h3.head-loans Loans
    a.book-new.nav(href='/book/new') New Book
    a.book-list-all.nav(href='/book?page=1') List All
    a.book-list-co.nav(href='/book?page=1&filter=checked_out') List Checked Out
    a.book-list-od.nav(href='/book?page=1&filter=overdue') List Overdue
    a.patron-new.nav(href='/patron/new') New Patron
    a.patron-list-all.nav(href='/patron?page=1') List All
    a.loan-new.nav(href='/loan/new') New Loan
    a.loan-list-all.nav(href='/loan?page=1') List All
    a.loan-list-co.nav(href='/loan?page=1&filter=checked_out') List Checked Out
    a.loan-list-od.nav(href='/loan?page=1&filter=overdue') List Overdue
.gap
```

and the selector pug

```
extends ./layout

block content
include ./includes/_head_nav
.card
    h2=`${title} - ${filter}`
    //if entity === "book"
    //    include ./includes/_book_search
    //if entity === "patron"
    //    include ./includes/_patron_search
    table
        include ./includes/_table_heads
        tbody
            if entity === "book"
                include ./includes/_table_rows_books
            if entity === "patron"
                include ./includes/_table_rows_patrons
            if entity === "loan"
                include ./includes/_table_rows_loans
    include ./includes/_pagination
```

Any help will be appreciated I have combed the Express documentation, the Sequelize documentation and even tried to learn some better debugging skills in VS Code, but I am completely dead in the water.

Comment: What is the error on your express server console?

Comment: If I understand your question then this is the answer:    GET http://localhost:3000/patron?page=1 500 (Internal Server Error)